# Maxmind GeoIP2 City Accuracy - what does "incorrectly resolved" mean?

Tags: geolocation, definition, maxmind

I'm trying to understand exactly what "incorrectly resolved" means for Maxmind. How incorrect is the answer? Does it mean that the city is just one city over or completely on the other side of the country?

Link for reference: 
https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-city-accuracy-comparison

Comment: Interesting question, I think your real question might be what is the testing methodology.